# Apply Function on List

Tags: python, django, list, django-views, django-queryset

I have a view method which returns a queryset of fee records in a paginated table

```
def fee_all(request):

    fee_list = Fee.objects.all().order_by('code') # query for records
    # How to apply separate function e.g. get_column_result 
    # to and append result on the fee_list?

    p = Paginator(fee_list,10) # paginate query
    page = request.GET.get('page') 
    fees = p.get_page(page) # pagination object instance

    context = { 
       'fee_list': fee_list,
       'fees': fees, 
        }

    return render(request, 'fee-all.html', context)

def get_column_result(fee):
    #do operations
    return column_result
```

[Table Sample that I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IorrU.png)

I want to apply a method/function for each queryset item to do a calculation and display the result as an additional column in the displayed table. Considering trying to use Data frames from Pandas with the apply() or Applying lambda function but conversion from resulting dataframe to queryset is difficult. Any ideas?

Comment: Add an example with some input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `annotate?`. It heavily depends on what your function do.

you can read more here about annotates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate

and here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations